# Почему метод не срабатывает корректно?

Tags: java

Почему-то на платформе Stepik не проходит метод.
Пишет, что провален тест.
Не пойму, что не так делаю? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Условие задачи:

Напишите программу, читающую из System.in текст в кодировке UTF-8, подсчитывающую в нем частоту появления слов, и в конце выводящую 10 наиболее часто встречающихся слов.

Словом будем считать любую непрерывную последовательность символов, состоящую только из букв и цифр. Например, в строке "Мама мыла раму 33 раза!" ровно пять слов: "Мама", "мыла", "раму", "33" и "раза".

Подсчет слов должен выполняться без учета регистра, т.е. "МАМА", "мама" и "Мама" — это одно и то же слово. Выводите слова в нижнем регистре.

Если в тексте меньше 10 уникальных слов, то выводите сколько есть.

Если в тексте некоторые слова имеют одинаковую частоту, т.е. их нельзя однозначно упорядочить только по частоте, то дополнительно упорядочите слова с одинаковой частотой в лексикографическом порядке.

Задача имеет красивое решение через стримы без циклов и условных операторов. Попробуйте придумать его.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

        (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .lines()
                .flatMap(l -> Stream.of(l.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")))
                .map(w -> w.toLowerCase())
                .forEach(w -> {
                    if (result.containsKey(w)) {
                        result.put(w, result.get(w) + 1);
                    } else {
                        result.put(w, 1);
                    }
                });

        result.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
                    if (e1.getValue() == e2.getValue()) {
                        return e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
                    } else {
                        return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
                    }
                })
                .limit(10)
                .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey()));
    }
```

Comment: Возможно ошибка в `e1.getValue() == e2.getValue()`, тут сравниваются ссылки, а не значения, нужно либо использовать equals, либо  `e1.getValue().intValue() == e2.getValue().intValue()`. Ещё возможно, что ключи тоже нужно в обратном порядке сортировать

Comment: спасибо! сейчас попробую)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот более изящная версия:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files
                .lines(Paths.get("freq.txt")))
        {
                lines
                    .flatMap(l -> Stream.of(l.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, Collectors.counting()))
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .sorted((e1, e2) ->
                    {
                        if (e1.getValue().equals(e2.getValue()))
                        {
                            return e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
                        } else
                        {
                            return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
                        }
                    })
                    .limit(10)
                    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey()));
        }
    }
```

Может, она подойдет

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую вечером.

Comment: Все отлично) Спасибо!